# How can I avoid huge amounts of code in anonymous class?

Tags: java

I inherited a bunch of Java code. I have been programming in C# for a while and C++ before that. There is a a Java issue that is causing me a headache; how can I move code out of a huge function in an anonymous class?

The code looks like this:

```
m_formsListView.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int iPosition, long iId) {
// AT LEAST 200 LINES OF CODE IN HERE!
    }
} );
```

The 200 lines of code in the contained function is just wrong for my coding style. The function that holds this has a lot of code and none of it is processing clicks so this code is a distraction. I want to simply pass a function reference but the version of Java I am using doesn't seem to support that. I can't manage to call an outside member function either.

Is this really how Java is designed, so that I can't better modularize the code so functions don't contain code for more than one specific operation? I would like to at least make my functions smaller to be more maintainable.

How can I move the code out of the anonymous class and into some function or method outside of the current method or function?

[edit]

Here is the solution I came up with thanks to all of the useful feedback and potential answers:

Have the class that contains all of this code implement the AdapterView.OnItemClickListener interface and just move the OnItemClick code out of here and into the outer class. Then I just pass the "this" pointer to the setOnItemClickListener method.

Here's the final code including the class definition of the class containing all of this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FormInitListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int iPosition, long iId) {
        ...
    }

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        ...
        m_formsListView.setOnItemClickListener( this );
        ...
    }
}
```

Interfaces are one of the few language features I have not used much in any language I write in. And I certainly blew it thinking initially that this was some sort of lambda expression.

Comment: I see no lambda.  I see an anonymous inner class, which isn't the *same* as a lambda but can be replaced by one.

Comment: Also...what Java version are you actually running?  You want to use a function reference but Java doesn't seem to support that; I could see this working in Java 8 or newer.

Comment: My mistake mixing up lambda and anonymous functions. Both are shown as ways to pass a function to another function. I'm targeting the oldest version of Android that I can reasonably target so I think I can't use Java 8.

Comment: You didn't post the actual problematic code. If a single method - be it in a regular or anonymous class has that many lines, it's time to refactor the code. 
If you don't like it in an anon class, move it to a concrete class (your favorite IDE can assist you)

Comment: The easiest solution is to move your 200 lines to a private method, then place a single call to that private method in your anonymous listener.

Comment: I need to write the code so that the 200 lines of inner code are elsewhere, not inline within the containing function. I think I must be misunderstanding the parameter to setOnItemClickListener, which is apparently an object, not a method. I need a JSL (Java as a second language) class to teach me a bit more before I ask badly formed questions.

Comment: I tried a private method but I now understand that I can't call private members of the outer class because this 200 lines of code is within the inner anonymous class.

Comment: I changed the question to not reference this as a lambda expression.

Comment: Apparently, I can access class member variables of the class outside of the anonymous class but I can't access a method of any sort in that same scope. I think I'm left with the code as-is.

Comment: Thanks to all of the feedback, I solved it in a fairly easy way. I'll post my solution in the original post but here it is: Have the class that contains all of this code implement the AdapterView.OnItemClickListener interface and just move the OnItemClick code out of here and into the outer class. Then I just pass the "this" pointer to the setOnItemClickListener method. That was simple and all of the quick and useful questions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous inner classes are useful for short implementations like event handlers, but they don't have to be used this way.

Define a new class that implements your `OnItemClickListener` interface, and then pass an instance of it to `setOnItemClickListener(...)`.

Comment: This is what led me to making the outer class, the one containing all of this code, be the class that implements the interface. No other class was needed in this specific case.